# Difference when the servlet url is mapped with / as suffix

Tags: javascript, html, css, servlets

I have a problem. When I map the url of my servlet with `/` as suffix I don't get the css stylesheets or javascript but only the text of my html page. it is really weird. For example

```
@WebServlet(name = "UserAreaServlet",
            urlPatterns = {"/user"})
```

In this way I get the page with all the css and js resources

while

```
@WebServlet(name = "UserAreaServlet",
            urlPatterns = {"/user/"})
```

in this way I get only the text without any css or js

Why?

Comment: The strange thing is that I see the text but css and js NOT. I'm using java ee 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slash afterwards makes it like a directory which changes the relative path.

Say my structure was:

```
webapps
  --myapp
     --css
        --style.css
     --servlet
```

The relative path to the css from `servlet` is `/css/style.css` (because servlet is treated as if its a file directly under myapp)

```
webapps
  --myapp
     --css
        --style.css
     --servlet/
```

The relative path to the css from `servlet/` is `../css/style.css` (because servlet/ is treated as a directory)

(I know in reality, on the filesystem, your servlet is under web-inf and so on, but from the url perspective its directly under the app context as in the diagrams above)